# Unable to generate xml reports using JUnitXmlReporter

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-reporters

When I am trying to generate xml output files using JUnitXmlReporter, the test run is successful, but no XML reports are generated, I only see results in console where I run the tests. Below is the conf.js file that I used:

```
exports.config = {
      seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

      capabilities: {
          'browserName': 'firefox'
      },

      specs: ['spec1.js'],

      jasmineNodeOpts: {
           onComplete: null,
           isVerbose: true,
           showColors: true,
           includeStackTrace: true
      },

      onPrepare: function() {
          var jasmineReporters = require('C:/Users/swati.m.khandelwal/node_modules/jasmine-reporters');
          jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter('./output', true, true)
          );
     }
   };
```

P.S. I am successfully able to generate HTML reports (using 'protractor-html-screenshot-reporter') but not XML reports anyhow.

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are using [`jasmine-reporters` 2.x](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters) which is made to work with `jasmine2` while `protractor` is using `jasmine1`. If you are planning to stay with `jasmine1`, [install `jasmine-reporters` 1.x](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters/tree/jasmine1.x):

```
npm install --save-dev jasmine-reporters@^1.0.0
```

Comment: Yes, i am using jasmine-reporters@2.0.7. Can I not generate XML reports using 2.x version instead of 1.x ?

Comment: Thanks buddy! I Your suggestion worked. Also, I realized that simply adding a statement **framework: 'jasmine2'** in the conf file also worked.